# When does the element-wise product $IJ$ form an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Given $I, J$ are ideals of $R$, what is a necessary condition (either on the ideals or the ring) to say the element-wise product
$$\tilde {IJ} = \{ij  : i\in I, j\in J\}$$
forms an ideal.

For example in $\mathbb{Z}$, $(2)(3) = (6)$; and this holds generally in PIDs since 
$$(a)(b) \ni ar_1 bs_1 +  \cdots + ar_n bs_n = ab(r_1s_1+\cdots r_ns_n) \in (ab) $$

Comment: Here may be a helpful fact: If you look at your example of $\mathbb{Z}$ you will see you just need one of the ideals to be principle.

Comment: Do you really mean *necessary condition* or did you actually want *sufficient conditions*?

Comment: @rschwieb I meant the most general sufficient condition, since taking $R$ to be PID would be one sufficient condition.

Comment: @SheelStueber hmm, what do you mean? Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID.

Comment: @Xiao Thanks for clarifying. I can't think of anything better than "at least one of the ideals is principal" like Sheel suggested.   S/he just means $\mathbb Z$ is a special case. It'll work like that in any commutative ring (if one of the ideals is principal, then the element-wise product is an ideal.)